# I2C Driver in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am aware of I2C in a very basic level which relies inside linux kernel, but no clue to implement a basic I2C driver.

Trying to moving for a start in **I2C** *device driver*.
could you please suggest any beginner tutorial with source code mapping !!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

linux-source/Documentation/i2c/ has lot of the information you'd need. .../writing-clients.txt is a good place to start.

Have a look at the online version:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/writing-clients

There is an okay sort of a tutorial at:

http://renjucnair.blogspot.ca/2012/01/writing-i2c-client-driver.html

Here is a good commentary on someone writing an i2c driver and has a tutorial feel to it:

http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2009/i2c-in-the-2632-linux-kernel/

Here is some sample code:

http://code.google.com/p/ldd-templates/source/browse/drivers/i2c/sample-i2c-client.c

Comment: Thank you Ahmed !!
I like your posts. I feel, I can see my code working from the 2nd link that you gave provided.
Awesome links..
upvoted !!

Comment: sure..
Here I accepted it !!

Comment: [This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/writing-clients) is a bit confusing, normally in a micro-controller you would initialize the registers, clock frequency, mode of operation, corresponding pins, etc, who does all that in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I2C driver is implemented as a platform driver in linux kernel.So first you need to understand the linux model for platform devices.

Please go through below documentation under linux kernel for platform devices:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt

You also need to understand the bus structure under linux kernel.Please refer to the below link:
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/driver-model/bus.txt

Now you can google for I2C drivers and further study.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the smbus modules available for many programming languages...then write the driver for your i2c device around that.